# Identical apps on App Store

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

Is it possible to have the same identical app on App Store, but under two different developer accounts, and slightly different names?

I need to move an app from one dev account to another, but I would like it uploaded on the new account before removing it from the old one.

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

The two apps will have to have unique and different iTunes Connect names and different Bundle IDs.  The only sure way to determine whether or not this is possible is to submit the new app, and see if Apple approves it.

Comment: Thanks. They have the same name, but the new app has some extra text afterwards. Will submit today and we will see. They have different Bundle IDs as they are on different accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same app "Smart Alarm Clock" by Arawella corp being sold both as a free version and as a paid version. They essentially have the same app twice in the app store, just with different icons. If a company that big can get away with that, you can probably too (paid and free version)